# PHP SESSION Items Not Carrying Across Pages

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to get $_SESSION items to carry across to/from different pages. I have verified that the "use_only_cookies=1" in the PHP.ini file. When the site is loaded initially the first page is "index.php". This page loads the main page, menus, etc. When the user presses the "Login" menu option the code launches the "login.php" file, and inside that file I set two $_SESSION fields one to indicate that the login was successful and the other to hold the user name. The code then using the header() function calls the "index.php" file where the session fields are now apparently NULL and not being evaluated correctly. Below are both files along with the HTML header file are show below. I have also looked at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849898/php-sessions-not-working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**File: Index.php**

```
      <?php
      session_start();
      $page_title='Welcome to this Site!';
      include('php/vmenus.php');
      include('html/header.html');

      ?>

    <!-- Image Slider -->
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div>
            <img src="images/test1.jpg" width="1000" height="600">  
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/test2.jpg" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/test3.jpg" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content Area -->
    <div id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column2left">

            <h1>Content Header</h1>

            <p>
        Paragraph of text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column2right"> 
        <p> The Right Side</p><br>
            <?php
                vmenustart();
                vmenuitem("#","Calendar");
                vmenuitem("#","Public Records");
                vmenuitem("#","Menu 3");
                vmenuitem("#","Menu 4");
                vmenuend();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
include('html/footer.html');
?>
```

**File: Login.php**

```
<?php
$page_title="Login";

// if user is already logged in to the website, then redirect them to the home page
// and terminated this script
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
header("location: index.php");
exit;
}

include('php/vmenus.php');
include('php/forms.php');

// open the master database code
require_once "php/dbconfig.php";

$username = "";
$password = "";
$username_err = "";
$password_err = "";

// Process FORM data when the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

//Check if username is empty
if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
    $username_err = "Please enter a valid username.";
}
else {
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

// Check if password is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

// Validate credentials
if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT UserID, Passwrd FROM Users WHERE UserID = ?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

        // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if (SHA1($password) == $hashed_password) {
                        // Password is correct
                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                        header("location: index.php");
                    } 
                    else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}       

include('html/header.html');

// start the page, check for errors
echo '<div class="page" style="font-family:arial">';
formStart("login.php","","wrapper");
formFieldSetStart("");
    echo '<h2 class="hdr-contactus">User Login</h2>';

    //check for errors, if errors then display them
    if (!empty($username_err) || !empty($password_err)) {
        echo '<h1>Error(s):</h1>';
        if (!empty($username_err)) {
            echo $username_err.'<br>';
        }
        if (!empty($password_err)) {
            echo $password_err.'<br>';
        }
    }

    formDivStart("fields");

        formParaStart("row");
        fieldAdd("text","username","User Name","Y","field-large","");
        formParaEnd();

        formParaStart("row");
        fieldAdd("password","password","Password","Y","field-large","");
        formParaEnd();

    formDivEnd();
formFieldSetEnd();

fieldAddSubmit("Login");

formEnd();
echo '</div>';

include('html/footer.html');
```

**File: Header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerimg">
    <img src="images/test1.jpg" width="150" height="125">
</div>  
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Sub-Title</h2>
</div>

<?php
    hmenustart();
    hmenuitem("#","Home");
    hmenudropstart("About");
        hmenudropitem("aboutus.php","About Us");
        hmenudropitem("#","Our History");
    hmenudropend();
    hmenudropstart("Board");
        hmenudropitem("#","Board Members");
        hmenudropitem("#","Committees");
        hmenudropitem("#","Documents");
        hmenudropitem("#","Message Baord");
    hmenudropend();
    hmenudropstart("Members");
        hmenudropitem("#","Calendar");
        hmenudropitem("#","FAQ");
        hmenudropitem("#","Member Directory");
        hmenudropitem("#","Member Documents");
        hmenudropitem("requestmgr.php","Member Requests");
        hmenudropitem("#","Questionaire");
    hmenudropend();
    hmenuitem("#","Photos");
    hmenuitem("contactus.php","Contact Us");

    if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
        hmenuitemfloatright("logout.php","Logout");
    }
    else {
        hmenuitemfloatright("login.php","Login");
    }

    hmenuend();
?>

<!-- Start of Page specific content --!>
```

Comment: Note, don't use SHA1 for password hashing, it is considered insufficient. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: I will make the appropriate changes for the SHA1 code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `session_start()` on every .php file.

Note that this should be the first thing on the webpage. Outputting HTML before calling the function will result in errors.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks you! It just doesn't seem logical to start a session on each page.

Comment: It basically fetches the session from disk and makes it available on $_SESSION variable. If all your requests pass through index.php and handlers are included later through require/include, then you don't need to call every .php file. In your case, both scripts are called separately, thats why you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That make more sense now.

Comment: My pleasure! :)